# Dynamic URL in OKTA redirect_uri

Tags: angular, types, okta

In my Angular application, I am using @okta/okta-signin-widget with okta client id. My requirement is to use window.location.origin as redirect_uri.

```
import { NgModule } from ‘@angular/core’;
import { AppComponent } from ‘./app.component’;
import { RoutesModule } from ‘./routes/routes.module’;

import { OktaAuthModule } from ‘@okta/okta-angular’;

// Okta configuration
const oktaConfig = {
issuer: ‘https://dev-836625.oktapreview.com/oauth2/default’,
redirectUri: window.location.origin,
clientId: ‘xxxXXXxxXxxx’,
scope: ‘openid profile email’
};

@NgModule({
declarations: [
AppComponent
],
imports: [

OktaAuthModule.initAuth(oktaConfig),
RoutesModule,
providers: [],
bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

After login redirect_uri should be window.location.origin, but redirect_uri is returned as null from OKTA widget. Please find the attachment.

[image]

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at your browser's address bar, you'll see there's a `redirect_uri` parameter in it that it's sending. If you add this URI to the Login redirect URIs in your OIDC application, everything should work.

Answer (score 1):

Have you whitelisted these URLs in OKTA settings?

Anyway, Let me advise you using the Angular `environment` files to set this configuration:

```
export const environment = {
  production: true,
  redirectUrl: 'YOUR_URL_FOR_THIS_ENV',
  ...
};
```